# Date Issue between daily and monthy dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have two tables which I need to join on using a date column.

`Table 1` contains daily records formatted like:

```
20160901
```

`Table 2` contains month end records formatted like:

```
2016-09-30 00:00:00.0000000
```

I need to bring in columns from `Table 2` and join on `Table 1`.  How can I do that?

Comment: How can your database be Oracle on SQL Server 2014? They're mutually exclusive - either you have an Oracle database, or an MS SQL Server database. Please clarify the question.

Comment: I am sorry it's oracle

Comment: What means formatted? Aren't the dates stored as dates? And then show sample data and expected results, please.

Comment: Please show the actual column data types.  Are they actual oracle DATE or TIMESTAMP type, or varchar?

Comment: So table 1 is a number (38,0) and table 2 is a date

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to store a date as an integer, for in an int you can easily store invalid dates by mistake. However, as to the join: simply convert both to get to the same type (both number or both date or both string). Does this already answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
table1 t1 join table2 t2 on (to_date(to_char(t1.column), 'yyyymmdd') = trunc(t2.column))
```